# An Element in a Very Simple VBA Array Has a Value of -1 and it Shouldn't

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In support of an Excel spreadsheet, I have a number of modules and classes that implement several UDFs.  In one of these classes, I have a simple private array of type `Long` and a single method that increments an element of the array.  In the class initializer, I set all elements of this array to zero (admittedly, this is unnecessary).  Another method of this class prints the contents of the array to a text file.  The first element is mysteriously -1.  I can see no way for any of the array elements to have a negative value.

Below is the entire class.  Below the class I point out the relevant parts of the class.  There are very few, making this an easy to understand question.

```
Option Explicit

Private m_FromLastMethodCalls As Long
Private m_FromLastBinarySearchMiss As Long
Private m_FromLastBinarySearchHit As Long
Private m_FromLastBinarySearchAdd As Long
Private m_FromLastBinarySearchLastHitIndex As Long
Private m_FromLastGuess(2) As Long
Private m_FromLastCreateTargetsCollection As Long
Private m_FromLastRetrieveCachedTargetsCollection As Long
Private m_FromLastError As Long

Public Function IncrementFromLastMethodCalls()
    m_FromLastMethodCalls = m_FromLastMethodCalls + 1
End Function
Public Function IncrementFromLastBinarySearchMiss()
    m_FromLastBinarySearchMiss = m_FromLastBinarySearchMiss + 1
End Function
Public Function IncrementFromLastBinarySearchHit()
    m_FromLastBinarySearchHit = m_FromLastBinarySearchHit + 1
End Function
Public Function IncrementFromLastBinarySearchAdd()
    m_FromLastBinarySearchAdd = m_FromLastBinarySearchAdd + 1
End Function
Public Function IncrementFromLastCreateTargetsCollection()
    m_FromLastCreateTargetsCollection = m_FromLastCreateTargetsCollection + 1
End Function
Public Function IncrementFromLastRetrieveCachedTargetCollection()
    m_FromLastRetrieveCachedTargetsCollection = m_FromLastRetrieveCachedTargetsCollection + 1
End Function
Public Function IncrementFromLastError()
    m_FromLastError = m_FromLastError + 1
End Function
Public Property Let lastHitIndex(lastHitIndex As Long)
    m_FromLastBinarySearchLastHitIndex = lastHitIndex
End Property
Public Property Get lastHitIndex() As Long
    lastHitIndex = m_FromLastBinarySearchLastHitIndex
End Property
Public Function IncrementFromLastGuess(guessNumber As Integer)
    m_FromLastGuess(guessNumber) = m_FromLastGuess(guessNumber) + 1
End Function


Public Function Dump()
    Open "statistics.txt" For Append As #1 ' Open file for output.
    Print #1, Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")
    Print #1, "FromLastMethodCalls:                     " & Format(Format(m_FromLastMethodCalls, "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Print #1, "FromLastBinarySearchMiss:                " & Format(Format(m_FromLastBinarySearchMiss, "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Print #1, "FromLastBinarySearchHit:                 " & Format(Format(m_FromLastBinarySearchHit, "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Print #1, "FromLastBinarySearchAdd:                 " & Format(Format(m_FromLastBinarySearchAdd, "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Print #1, "FromLastGuess(0):                        " & Format(Format(m_FromLastGuess(0), "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Print #1, "FromLastGuess(1):                        " & Format(Format(m_FromLastGuess(1), "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Print #1, "FromLastGuess(2):                        " & Format(Format(m_FromLastGuess(2), "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Print #1, "FromLastError:                           " & Format(Format(m_FromLastError, "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Print #1, "FromLastCreateTargetsCollection:         " & Format(Format(m_FromLastCreateTargetsCollection, "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Print #1, "FromLastRetrieveCachedTargetsCollection: " & Format(Format(m_FromLastRetrieveCachedTargetsCollection, "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Dim total As Long
    total = m_FromLastError + m_FromLastCreateTargetsCollection + m_FromLastRetrieveCachedTargetsCollection
    Print #1, "Total:                                   " & Format(Format(total, "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
    Close #1
    
    m_FromLastMethodCalls = 0
    m_FromLastBinarySearchMiss = 0
    m_FromLastBinarySearchHit = 0
    m_FromLastBinarySearchAdd = 0
    m_FromLastGuess(0) = m_FromLastGuess(1) = m_FromLastGuess(2) = 0
    m_FromLastCreateTargetsCollection = 0
    m_FromLastRetrieveCachedTargetsCollection = 0
    m_FromLastError = 0
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_FromLastBinarySearchLastHitIndex = -1
    m_FromLastGuess(0) = m_FromLastGuess(1) = m_FromLastGuess(2) = 0
End Sub
```

Note the declaration of `m_FromLastGuess`.  It is private.  It is an array consisting of 3 elements of type `Long`.

Note the method `IncrementFromLastGuess`.  It is the only method that modifies the array and the only thing it can do is *increment* one of the array elements.

Note the method `Dump`, specifically these lines:

```
Print #1, "FromLastGuess(0):                        " & Format(Format(m_FromLastGuess(0), "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
Print #1, "FromLastGuess(1):                        " & Format(Format(m_FromLastGuess(1), "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
Print #1, "FromLastGuess(2):                        " & Format(Format(m_FromLastGuess(2), "##,###,##0"), "@@@@@@@@@@")
```

Here is the contents of `statistics.txt`, the file `Dump` produces:

```
2023-05-26 10:41:54
FromLastMethodCalls:                              0
FromLastBinarySearchMiss:                         0
FromLastBinarySearchHit:                          0
FromLastBinarySearchAdd:                          0
FromLastGuess(0):                                -1
FromLastGuess(1):                            10,535
FromLastGuess(2):                               856
FromLastError:                                    0
FromLastCreateTargetsCollection:                  0
FromLastRetrieveCachedTargetsCollection:          0
Total:                                            0
```

Note that the printed value of `FromLastGuess(0)` is -1.  How can this be?  The variable `m_FromLastGuess` is private, so nothing else in my project can change it and the only thing this class can do is increment it, print it and set it to zero.

Comment: `m_FromLastGuess(0) = m_FromLastGuess(1) = m_FromLastGuess(2) = 0` is `m_FromLastGuess(0) = (m_FromLastGuess(1) = (m_FromLastGuess(2) = 0))`.  Which assigns the result of `m_FromLastGuess(1) = (m_FromLastGuess(2) = 0)` (which is `True`) to `m_FromLastGuess(0)`, and does no other assignment. `True` is `-1` in VB.

Comment: @GSerg Yes.  Post this as an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks.

Comment: There can no longer be answers as the question has been closed as a duplicate.